# How does CHAR(n) represent its data in binary?

Tags: mysql, database, binary, char, mariadb

I am currently reading Robin Nixon's *Learning PHP, MySQL, & JavaScript* book. In particular the chapters on databases using MySQL. Here is the topic that I am struggling to thoroughly understand.

"The year field, however, has more-predictable values, so instead of VARCHAR we use the more efficient CHAR(4) data type. The parameter of 4 allows for 4 bytes of data, supporting all years from –999 to 9999; a byte comprises 8 bits and can have the values 00000000 through 11111111, which are 0 to 255 in decimal."

In the example above, CHAR(4) is set to store 4 characters that will represent a four digit year entry. Why is it that -999 to 9999 are the only options. How is it represented in binary that it is limited to just those values? My original thought process was that since 4 bytes is 32 bits and if all 32 bits are set to 1, 2^32 is about 4 Billion unsigned and about 2 Billion signed, that would be the amount that could be stored.

I appreciate any explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The book you quoted seems to be suggesting using CHAR to store year values, even though this does not store in binary, it stores digit *characters*. You are correct that four bytes could store a much greater range if you use the bytes to store a binary value of the number.

It's surprising that the book is concerned about the single extra byte needed to encode the length for a VARCHAR, then it uses CHAR to store numeric year values in such an inefficient way.

It's an example of "penny wise, pound foolish."

Take this book (or any book) with a grain of salt. Remember that tech books are written by people, and they can make mistakes.

Comment: And when a book is in print before the product is released, be suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

First all, for limited year values use [**YEAR**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) (yyyy, 1901 to 2155, or 0000): 1 byte.

- **INT(4)** can be stored in 2 bytes and would be best (as it has no year 2156 problem). *Actually 4 bytes; **SMALL INT** takes 2 bytes, as @BillKarwin mentions.*
- **CHAR(4)** in general (single byte charset) is limited to 4 bytes, and but CHAR is padded with spaces, like `'712 '` and cannot immediatedly be used with arithmetic.
- **VARCHAR(4)** needs more than CHAR(4) and allows also smaller strings `'712'`.

Comment: `INT` is always four bytes, regardless of the `(4)` argument. `SMALLINT` is two bytes.

Comment: `VARCHAR(4)` has a 1-byte length field.  So, for shorter strings it is more compact than `CHAR` and for full-sized strings less compact.

Comment: @RickJames thanks; the main difference in my view is, that CHAR is padded with blanks, so VARCHAR seems a logical choice, size or no size.